# Changing Shape Quantity Based On Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have a macro that produces a scaled shape based on user inputted dimensions on the "enter information" sheet.  The macro is linked to a button and once the button is clicked the shape appears on the user chosen sheet (ws - ws5) and the shape dimensions, quantity, and description are added to the "Vessel BOM" sheet.  The user can input the quantity of shapes into a cell on the "enter information" sheet too, but so far I have been unable to link the shape quantity to produce more than one shape.

Right now I have another button (essentially the same macro but without adding the shape details to the "vessel BOM" sheet) the user can use to create additional shapes if the chosen quantity is more than one.  I am attempting to eliminate that extra work.

```
Sub AddShapeToCell()

Dim s As Shape
Dim r As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Deep Blue")
Set ws1 = Sheets("GC II")
Set ws2 = Sheets("300ft Barge")
Set ws3 = Sheets("275ft Barge")
Set ws4 = Sheets("250ft Barge")
Set ws5 = Sheets("User Defined Vessel")
Dim TriggerCellb As Range
Set TriggerCellb = Range("D8")
Const scaling As Double = 2.142857


'Create a shape

If TriggerCellb.Value = "Deep Blue" Then
Set s = ws.Shapes.AddShape(Cells(4, 17), 53, 66, Cells(20, 4) * scaling * 
Cells(5, 17), Cells(22, 4) * scaling * Cells(5, 17))

ElseIf TriggerCellb.Value = "GC II" Then
Set s = ws1.Shapes.AddShape(Cells(4, 17), 53, 66, Cells(20, 4) * scaling * 
Cells(5, 17), Cells(22, 4) * scaling * Cells(5, 17))

ElseIf TriggerCellb.Value = "300ft Barge" Then
Set s = ws2.Shapes.AddShape(Cells(4, 17), 53, 66, Cells(20, 4) * scaling * 
Cells(5, 17), Cells(22, 4) * scaling * Cells(5, 17))

ElseIf TriggerCellb.Value = "275ft Barge" Then
Set s = ws3.Shapes.AddShape(Cells(4, 17), 53, 66, Cells(20, 4) * scaling * 
Cells(5, 17), Cells(22, 4) * scaling * Cells(5, 17))

ElseIf TriggerCellb.Value = "250ft Barge" Then
Set s = ws4.Shapes.AddShape(Cells(4, 17), 53, 66, Cells(20, 4) * scaling * 
Cells(5, 17), Cells(22, 4) * scaling * Cells(5, 17))

ElseIf TriggerCellb.Value = "User Defined Vessel" Then
Set s = ws5.Shapes.AddShape(Cells(4, 17), 53, 66, Cells(20, 4) * scaling * 
Cells(5, 17), Cells(22, 4) * scaling * Cells(5, 17))

End If
'make it nearly white
s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(245, 245, 255)

'show text within it
s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("d12").Value
s.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2

With s.TextFrame.Characters(0, 0)
s.TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
s.TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

End With

'add to BOM
Dim lastCell As Range
Set lastCell = Sheets("Vessel BOM").Range("C" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Sheets("Enter Information").Range("g20:m20").Copy
lastCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Sheets("Enter Information").Range("g20:m20").Copy
lastCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but you can create multiple shapes like so for example

```
Sub x()

Dim s As Shape, i As Long

For i = 1 To range("A1").value
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeBevel, 10, 20 * i, 10, 10)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, SJR.  I would like the user to input a number into a cell.  If that number is 2, then two shapes appear when the button is clicked.  If that number is 20, then 20 shapes appear what the button is clicked.

Comment: In that case just base the loop on the value of the cell rather than hardcoding 5. `for i=1 to range("a1").value`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Now I need to find a way to offset the shapes on the sheet once they are created.

Comment: Glad that helped. You have to play around with the top/left/height/width parameters. In the example the shapes appear in a vertical line as I only varied the top value.